# get JSON data in to jquery mobile and process

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to get json data array to JQM app and display colors according to that. Here is my link for the json array;
[daily health](http://iilsfa.br0s.info/Dashboard/get_daily_report.php)
My app contains a listview.

```
    <div>
      <ul data-role="listview">
            <li> 
            <a href="#pageone" data-transition="slideup">
                <img src="img/green.png"/>
            Outstanding Debits 
            <span class="ui-li-count">5</span>
            </a>
            </li>
             <li>
            <a href="#pagethree" data-transition="slideup">
                 <img src="img/red.png"/>
            Claim Provisions
            <span class="ui-li-count">1</span>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
            <a  href="#pagefour"  data-transition="slideup">
                <img src="img/dark_yellow.png"/>
            Premium Income
            <span class="ui-li-count">2</span>
            </a>
            </li>
           <li> 
            <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slideup">
                <img src="img/green.png"/>
            Sales Target Achievement- Month
            <span class="ui-li-count">4</span>
            </a>
            </li>
           <li> 
            <a href="#pagefive" data-transition="slideup">
                <img src="img/yellow.png"/>
            Sales Target Achievement- Year
            <span class="ui-li-count">3</span>
            </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
  </div>
```

This list have an image (img src=...) I want to display health state images (these images contains a color-red,dark yellow,yellow,light green,green) on that  according to the JSON data. (if 5 then green,4 light green,3 yellow,2 dark yellow,1 red) Im new to the JQM and Phonegap.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Json Success, call a JavaScript function before initiating your JQM page. In that function according to the Json array add the paths to image URLs using if conditions. In JQM there are events before page create, init..[JQM page events](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_page.asp) , [JQM events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/). So in those functions you can manipulate the DOM and change the image paths.